# How do save a value in a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to save the result of the variable `$res` into a multi-dimensional array to then save in the `json_encode`.

```
<?php

include("config.inc");

$query = "SELECT * FROM accounts ";
$res = mysql_query($query);

$arr = array(array($res));
echo json_encode($arr);

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I save the `$res` into an array? Thx

Oh also I need this to be showed in this way:
["aa","bb","cc"]
["aa","bb","cc"]
it will be saved into a table inside a program

Comment: `mysql_query` doesn't return the rows from the database.  Check the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: What does the echo output?

Comment: If `array()` didn't work what made you think `array(array())` would?

Comment: I'm sorry it just... I don't know :/

Comment: It will be salved into table in a program, so I need this line per line in this way: ["aa","bb","cc"]....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're only storing the resource. Use this instead:

```
$arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $arr[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

I'd really recommend switching from the deprecated mysql_* functions to PDO or mysqli, or else your code won't function with the next version of PHP.

Comment: Thank you so much thats worked very well, I'm really noob with php so I dont know much things but thanks, I'll try in mysqli like you said

Comment: There is a little problem, it will show me something like that:
[{"0":"16","ID":"16","1":"Diego350","Login":"Diego350","2":"Diego350","Nome":"Diego350","3":"sdasdasd@hotmail.com","Email":"sdasdasd@hotmail.com","4":"senha123","Senha":"senha123"}]
And I need it in this way:
["16","Diego350","Diego350","sdasdasd@hotmail.com","senha123"]
Is there anything wrong? thx :p

Comment: I'm not familiar with json, so I couldn't say. It might be because it's an array within an array, so you might want to try `echo json_encode($arr[0])`